# I'm looking for a way to test my angular component function through jasmine, but have no idea how to check a simply toggle funcion

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

```
  showUserInfo(id: number) {
    this.usuarioSelecionado = id;
    this.mostrarConteudo = this.mostrarConteudo ? false : true;
  }
```

i'm doing this in spec, trying to pass a boolean value but without success:

```
it('show more informations about the user', () => {

    expect(this.component.mostrarUsuarioInfo(this.id)).toBe('true')
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toBe('true')` doesn't check for a `boolean` value but for a `string` of value `"true"`. In order to check for a boolean value, remove the apostrophes.

```
it('show more informations about the user', () => {
    expect(this.component.mostrarUsuarioInfo(this.id)).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if you think it was the solution to your question (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)